# Why Audio Transforming Functions and Audio Visualizations are not connecting to streaming source

Tags: html5-audio, audio-recording, web-audio-api, voice-recording

I am working with **Web Audio API** and I *combined two project repositories at GitHub* to get a cool app that gets a streaming user input, transforms the input and provides an output for the user to download. I have a problem to connect the streaming voice with filters(pitch etc.), audio visualizations and a distortion filter. I am a student and I do not have much experience with audio API. Can anybody help me? (First Repository: https://github.com/mdn/web-dictaphone, Second Repository: https://github.com/urtzurd/html-audio/tree/gh-pages/static, My project Repository: https://github.com/PatrykWajs/web-dictaphone).

Thank you for your time.

I managed to combine both repositories as one project but I cannot understand why things cannot connect. I tried various things.

There Aren't Any errors. It seems like everything is working fine but streaming voice input is not connected to filters and visualization.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is working just fine; however, you're getting hit by the autoplay restrictions.  If you open up the developer console, you'll see a message that tells you so - the AudioContext will not go into playing mode unless it's created (or resume()ed) from within a user gesture (like a click handler).  You can test this by going into the site settings (right-click the lock icon in the address bar, click "Site Settings") and set "Audio" to "Allow" instead of "auto".

Comment: Wow, it seems that something is completely wrong and I cannot understand what is happening. When I run my project on Github it does not ask me for permission on audio input (microphone) and so I cannot push the record button and store the voice clips. When I run it locally on Windows everything is working fine except audio visualizer and audio effects cannot connect to the input source. When I run it on Kali Linux it gives me the message "your browser does not support web media API". I do not understand. Does anybody know what is happening here?